# Show select options based on choice from previous se;lection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following....

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" id="activity" name="activity"> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Activity</option>
                <option id ="1" value="1" >Paintball</option>
                <option id ="2" value="2" >Laser Tag</option>
                <option id ="3" value="3" >Splatball</option>
                <option id ="4" value="4" >Airsoft</option>
            </select>
<select class="form-control" id="session" name="session" required></select>
```

JS

```
(function ($) {
$('#activity').change(function() {
            var options = '';
            if($(this).val() == '1') {
                options = '<option value="1">Morning: 09.30 - 12.30</option><option value="2">All Day: 09:30 - 16:00</option><option value="3">Afternoon: 13:00 - 16:00</option>';
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == '2'){
                options = '<option value="5">Session 1: 09:30 - 11:30</option><option value="6">Session 2: 12:00 - 14:00</option><option value="7">Session 3: 14:30 - 16:30</option>';
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == '3'){
                options = '<option value="9">Session 1: 09:30 - 11:30</option><option value="10">Session 2: 12:00 - 14:00</option><option value="11">Session 3: 14:30 - 16:30</option><option value="12">Session 4: 16:30 - 18:30</option>';
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == '4'){
                options = '<option value="14">Full Day: 09:30 - 16:30</option>';
            }

            $('#session').html(options).show();
        });
})(jQuery);
```

I am trying to only get the certain options showing in the second select box, based on the first selection, but I cant get the bloody thing to work. Not seeing any errors in devtools either.

Comment: Make sure DOM is ready, put your script after HTML.

Comment: Yup, should be working. I simplified it with a switch statement: http://jsfiddle.net/b659xmsc/

Comment: FFS. Yep, works perfectly as long as JS is after HTML. Im going to go drink now. Thankyou!!!

Comment: `(function($)` is not the same as `$(function()` which is shorthand for `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @charlietfl I had it in (function($) because $ is undefined in Drupal, not attempting shorthand

Comment: @blex Can you post that as an answer mate? Ill accept it

Comment: understandable but can use both when code preceeds the html

Comment: @Collins that was just a tip. Prashant, however, posted a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move your script after the html, it will work.